# Python POST JSON - Is a web framework required?

Tags: javascript, python, json, angularjs

Im a bit new to python and trying to understand a simple JSON POST example (I am using AngularJS).  I have read other Q's on SO and I see most folks use some type of framework (ie, cherrypy).

I am able to send data (strings) via POST and upon .success, display it in a simple alert.  But only if I wrap the strings in html tags in the python code itself.  However, when I take the HTML tags out of the python script and try to return a JSON object, I get a 500 server error.  So my gut is telling me, I must use a web framework?

Code for the failing JSON attempt.

JS:

```
tableModule.factory('Service', ['$http',
function($http) {
    return {
        post : function($path, $data, callback) {
            return $http.post($path, $data,{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'} }  ).success(callback);
        }

...
Service.post('test.cgi', $.param($data), function(data, status){...
```

And the python is very simple:

```
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
import traceback
import json

cgitb.enable()

def getData1():

    ...generate json data...

    json_string = json.dumps(dictResult)
    return json_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        #htmlTop() <-- code not shown, when I wrap the python in html, i can return simple strings
        getData1()
        #htmlBottom()
    except:
        cgi.print_exception()
```

Is there a way to get this simple example working without installing a framework?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "no". A framework is just some code written by someone to do a bunch of common things - e.g. setting the HTTP headers or handling cookies. Instead of using a framework, you could write your own code to do these things. The advantage of frameworks is they are written by someone else (saving you time) and tend to be well thought out in terms of code structure.

As a further example of how a framework is just code written by someone else, you can view the source code for cherrypy here: https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src

Regarding your example, the best place to look is your server's error logs. https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#testing-your-cgi-script

I'm not very familiar with the CGI module, but don't you need to `print` the output and that gets sent to the client? The getData1 function looks like it returns the json_string to the main body and then does nothing with it - no printing.

What server are you using by the way? Perhaps the problem is something like it can auto-detect the content-type for HTML but not for json and you need to specify that in your output.

```
print "Content-type:text/json\r\n\r\n"
```

Comment: after posting my question, I came across `print "Content-type:text/json\r\n\r\n"` in another SO question.  The 500 error has disappeared which looks promising, and it looks like the JSON data is making its way back to the client - but I still have some troubleshooting to do.